# Perl regex extract parts of string with multiple condition

Tags: regex, perl

What's the single regex that enables me to capture 
all the text that goes after `are genes` and `is gene`
from this text

```
The closest human genes of best are genes A B C
The closest human gene of best is gene A
```

Hence I hope to extract `$1` that contain

```
A B C
A
```

Tried this but fail:

```
$line =~ /The closest .* gene[s] (.*)$/;
```

Comment: Do you also need to avoid illegal strings like "... gene of best are A"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$line =~ /The closest .* genes? (.*)$/;
```

Comment: +1 for matching requester's example as close as possible, but this could benefit from some information explaining that [s] is the same as s, [s ] would have been what he was trying to accomplish with that, and that s? is equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most explicit is:

```
$line =~ m/best \s (?:is \s gene|are \s genes) \s ([\p{IsUpper}](?: \s [\p{IsUpper} ])*)/x;
```

Of course if you know that all sentences are going to be grammatical, then you can do the `(?:are|is)` thing. And if you know that you're only going to have genes A-N or something, you can forget the `\p{IsUpper}` and use `[A-N]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -F/genes*/ -ane 'print $F[-1];' file
 A B C
 A
```

Answer (score 2):

Use non-greedy at the beginning to reduce the opportunities for surprises. Use non-capturing parens to group alternatives that you don't care about. Append `?` to a letter to make it optional. Hence, try this:

```
$line =~ /The closest .*? (?:is|are) genes? (.*)$/;
```

To see where you were going wrong BTW, just compare the above with what you were originally trying.

Comment: It captures some cases that are bad grammar too (“The closest ... is genes ..”) but that's hardly important, yes? :-)

Comment: if it's not important why bother with that non-capturing group at all?

Comment: @SilentGhost: Without it, you'll capture from the first instance of the word "gene" to the end, e.g., “`of best are genes A B C`”.

Comment: that's only because of using non-greedy quantifier

Comment: There's not really enough input data samples in the question to be able to work out what is wanted. I personally prefer to match more in the fixed proportion to reduce the number of landmines^Wsurprises in the matched text.

Answer (score 0):

With the other suggestions, I would like to suggest to have a look at the [perllre for Regular Expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)